# Encoding cue points for .webm video in Google Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, video, webm

I've run into a problem with converting our .mp4 videos to .webm so they will run in Google Chrome in HTML5.  The project we're working on features videos that stop at a cue point to allow user interaction, then continue on to the end once the interactive segment is completed.  The problem is that, when playing the .webm video, the player always seems to skip over the cue points in Google Chrome.  We tested the same video in Firefox and it recognizes the cue points just fine.  I'm not that familiar with the video encoding process, but the people on our team who are have had no luck figuring this problem out either.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you give some specifics on how you're converting to `.webm`? Any info about how the original videos are created, and converted would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to convert an .mp4 to an webm. Mp4 shod work in chrome.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <video style="object-fit: fill; width: 960px; height: 540px;" controls>
        <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

Ask if you need some help with something else.
Or if I misunderstood something.